# Using SQL Server DB over a network

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

[image]I want to use my SQL Server DB over a network.  I have setup server client applications.
The thing is for my current DB, I need to give it to server administrator who attaches the DB to SQLExpress instance and only then my network computers can access that.
My question is, is there any way that my vb.net application could attach this DB through code at runtime, and DB gets all rights that are necessary to access it over the network?

I can attach DB using Create procedure but for this I need to know the sa password.  Is there any way that I could achieve the same goal without sa passord and sa intervention?

My only purpose is to enable my DB to be accessible over the network with all read /Write rights.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using smo. But you need username and password for that. Otherwise you can go for Windows authentication. In that case you will require Admin windows username and password.

Without the user name and password, you cannot access the db over network. That is the meaning of security. Otherwise anyone can access your data.

Comment: I understand this but I have installed an application, having downloaded from download.com.  The application is inflow Inventory.  After installation, when I checked in SSMS, there was an instance \inflow and inflow DBs were attached to it with all rights?  How? I am going to attach a pic to my question for explanation

Comment: Are you sure this application did not require any admin privilages while starting?

Comment: sure ! but I will uninstall and install it again to watch carefully